# How to link an appended title?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, local-storage

I currently have an editor that allows users to enter input and save their input under a specific title. I have a button which allows them to do so, as well as adding the name of their title to a box (just a div with white background) using append child.

Was wondering how I could link these titles, such that when they click on one title, the text input assigned to said title shows up inside my editor?

Javascript:

```
    <!-- Function to save the user's input inside editor1 -->
    function saveEdits() {
        var editElem = document.getElementById("editor1");
        var userVersion = editElem.innerHTML;
        localStorage.userEdits = userVersion;

        //Get the title from the user
        var title = prompt("What would you like your title to be?");
        localStorage.setItem(title, editElem.innerHTML);

        //Asigning the titles input by the user to the key "titles"
        titles = localStorage.getItem("titles");

        if (titles == null){
            titles = [];
        }
        else {
            titles = JSON.parse(titles);
        }

        var obj;
        obj = {"titles": title};
        titles.push(obj);
        localStorage.setItem("titles",JSON.stringify(titles));

        //Save the editor contents to local storage based on title
        document.getElementById("update").innerHTML = "Edits saved!";
        var theDiv = document.getElementById("Contentable");
        var content = document.createTextNode(title);
        theDiv.appendChild(content);
        var br = document.createElement("br");
        theDiv.appendChild(br);

    }

    <!-- Function to check if the user has any saved input -->
    function checkEdits() {
        if(localStorage.userEdits != null)
        document.getElementById("editor1").innerHTML = localStorage.userEdits;
    }

    function loadEdits(title) {
        //load useredit for title from local storage
        var userEdits = localStorage.getItem(title);
        var editElem = document.getElementById("editor1");
        editElem.innerHTML = userEdits;
    }
```

HTML (Editor):

```
<!-- Editor 1 -->
    <div id="editor1" contenteditable="true" style="margin-left:30em">
    </div>
    <input id="savechanges" type="button" value="Save Changes" onclick="saveEdits()"/>
    <div id="update">Click to save your changes made</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could attach an onclick-event to the markup. Like this.

```
<div class="container>
<h2 class="title" onclick="edit(this)">
   EDITABLE CONTENT BELOW
</h2>
<div class="editable" onclick="edit(this)">
</div>
```

The js

```
var activeParent;
function edit( element ){
    var title = element.parentNode.children[ 0 ].innerHTML;
    var content = element.parentNode.children[ 1 ].innerHTML;
    //do stuff with the markup
    activeParent = element.parentNode; 
}
```

That is how you can get the content and temporarily store the active parent as a reference. So when you save it is `activeParent.children[ 1 ].innerHTML = editedContent`.

EDIT: Since all of these are relative references you can use as many as you want. Just be careful when using the activeParent. It assumes you only edit one area at a time.